# Trouble in fetching results from PostgreSQL table using PDO

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo

I have database named **testDB** and one table **test_tbl** in it with three fields **ID, User, Pass** in PostgreSQL database on Mac OS X.

I am using following php code to fetch results from the table.

```
<?php
try {
    $dbuser = 'postgres';
    $dbpass = 'test123';
    $dbhost = 'localhost';
    $dbname='testDB';

    $connec = new PDO("pgsql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error : " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
}

$sql = 'SELECT ID, User, Pass FROM test_tbl ORDER BY ID';

foreach ($connec->query($sql) as $row) {
    print $row['ID'] . " ";
    print $row['User'] . "-->";
    print $row['Pass'] . "<br>";
}
```

It's raising following error:

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /Users/nikko/Sites/pg_conn2.php on line 12
```

Comment: Can you add `PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE =>  PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION` for your connection options ?

Comment: You mean this way:
$connec->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

Comment: That or 4th parameter of PDO class as array.

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42703]: Undefined column: 7 ERROR: column "id" does not exist LINE 1: SELECT ID, User, Pass FROM test_tbl ^ in /Users/Nikko/Sites/pg_conn2.php:12 Stack trace: #0 /Users/Nikko/Sites/pg_conn2.php(12): PDO->query('SELECT ID, User...') #1 {main} thrown in /Users/Nikko/Sites/pg_conn2.php on line 12

Comment: Then your query is the problem, check your table columns and query.

Comment: OK, I was able to solve the problem. There is problem with PostgreSQL if you use caps in fields names then this exception is thrown. I changed the fields to small caps and it starts working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem. There is problem with PostgreSQL if you use caps in database table fields names then this exception is thrown. I changed the fields to small caps and it starts working. – Nikko just now   edit

Answer (score 1):

Postgres is not case sensitive regarding fieldnames

```
SELECT anyfield, id FROM mytable;

SELECT AnyField, ID FROM mytable;
```

Both will work.

Maybe the problem is that PDO is quoting field names like in

```
SELECT "AnyField", "ID" FROM mytable;
```

You can read Postgres log on your server to see the actual statement.

Besides, you should catch `$connec->query($sql)` before using it as an array. Perhaps PDO is returning `false` as a result when querying a bad formed statement.

Comment: OK, Here is the link from where I get info to solve the problem. It says the problem is caused by the way pg handles CAPS.https://www.drupal.org/project/currency/issues/2007388

Comment: Many versions ago, ID was a reserved word in Postgres. So, if you wanted to have a column named ID, you should define and use it quoted like this: "ID". If your table was created with quoted column names, you'll have to quote always to use them in statements. [Postgres manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS)

Comment: OK, thank you. I encountered same problem with 'user'. I had a field as 'user' but when fetching values, it was always postgres as value for each row. Then I renamed it to 'login' and table values were fetched. So I need to use same technique there too as you described for id.